# why does "ssh root@server" need a id_dsa key?

Tags: ssh, deployment, permissions, rsa

#### Why find .ssh/iddsa file. there is no such a file. just id_rsa.

So the issue is that I can login to my server just fine using:

`ssh root@SERVER_IP_ADRESS`

But when I try to login with a user I created from root:

`ssh USERNAME@SERVER_IP_ADRESS5`

I get:

#### Permission denied (publickey).

The steps I went through before this.

SSH generated a key
Created an Ubuntu 16.04 droplet with given SSH key.
SSH into server with root

`$ adduser username
usermod -aG sudo username`

```
`$ ssh -vvv root@serverip

OpenSSH7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/sshconfig
debug1: /etc/ssh/sshconfig line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: sshconnectdirect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to cleanproject port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/happy/.ssh/idrsa type 0
....
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/happy/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/happy/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/happy/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/happy/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/happy/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/happy/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

#### root@server: Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: you need to create new user and add to the instance, since only root is allowed as default

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Below steps should help to create and authenticate the new user on the instance.

- Ssh into your instance using public key.
- Create a new user:  `$ sudo adduser test123`
- Change the shell session: `$ sudo su test123`
- Create .ssh folder: `$mkdir .ssh`
- Change the permission: `$ chmod 700 .ssh`
- Confirm `$pwd` is /home/test123

In .ssh folder, execute these

```
$ touch authorized_keys
$ chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

paste your public key here from your local system, id_rsa.pub is the default name if not edited while saving. make sure no extra spaces are copied.

It should work!.

```
$ssh test123@ip-address
```